# Memory warning when I go to google Images

Tags: ios, objective-c

Has anyone experienced something similar? When I google 'red' and select images everything is fine. But when i select one of the images i get a memory warning. And the functionality of the app goes to hell from there.

this is how i handle my URLCache in my app delegate

```
int cacheSizeMemory = 4*1024*1024; // 4MB
int cacheSizeDisk = 32*1024*1024; // 32MB
NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
```

and

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"Clear cache");
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
}
```

Any help or direction to research would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: The best place to start is with the Allocations tool in Instruments.  Profile your app and select Allocations when Instruments gives you a choice of tools.  Do your search and select and image, and take a look at your memory usage.  If you expand the info panel on the right in Instruments you can see your heaviest stack traces, which should help you figure out exactly where the memory is being used.

Comment: Could you go into more detail on the info panel on the right, when i open it it reads 'Extended Detail' how do i see the heaviest stack traces

Comment: Memory warnings are to be expected; they're not necessarily the sign of anything wrong. Why does the functionality of the app go to hell when you receive one? Or, what exactly do you mean by "goes to hell"?

Comment: @JamesDunay Sorry, should have included before: Near the center of the Instruments window look for the "Statistics" button right above the table of all your allocations.  Click-hold Statistics and select "Call Trees."  Once you do that the Heaviest Stack Trace should appear in the Extended Detail panel.

Comment: @JesseRusak haha sorry, "Goes to hell" = buttons seem to be called twice for every single tap after I receive the warning, I checked to see if they were added twice to the view, but they were only added once...

Comment: @JamesDunay That sounds like some code is calling `[yourButton addTarget:action:...]` in `viewDidLoad` or something similar, even though the button may already have been hooked up. I highly recommend looking into fixing that issue rather than chasing the source of the memory warning. (Since even if you do nothing wrong, you may still get memory warnings due to other apps in the background, system activity, etc.)